# Enabling FTPES and normal FTP connections on vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

vsftpd was automatically installed onto my Ubuntu server to allow FTPES connections by some auto installer script I ran. How can I enable it to auto accept normal FTP connections as well? Is this possible?

Is there some configuration changes that can be made to `/etc/vsftpd.conf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have googled more and looked at the [vsftpd man pages](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)

I needed to edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and set `force_local_data_ssl` and `force_local_logins_ssl` to false. and then restart with `sudo service vsftpd restart`

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark at the left of the answer. This way the question will be marked as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @BloodPhilia: IIRC, own answers can only be accepted after a certain time period.

Comment: @grawity I know, it's a mere reminder. ;)

Comment: It's a two day wait unfortunately :/